# How many convergent sequences of real numbers verify the relation $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{10}x_{n + k}^2 = 10$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to find how many convergent sequences of real numbers $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ verify the relation:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{10}x_{n+k}^2 = 10$$

for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I am given the following options:

**A.** $1$

**B.** $10$

**C.** $0$

**D.** An infinity

**E.** $2$

I have never done anything like this before, so this seems very alien to me. How should I approach this?

Comment: He was probably intending to say $\sum_{k=0}^{9}x_{n+k}^2 = 10$ rather than $\sum_{k=1}^{10}x_{n+k}^2 = 10$

Comment: @JosephCamacho I don't know, I copied the exercise correctly from my textbook and it really is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{10}x_{n+k}^2=10$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the two equations
\begin{align}
x_n^2~ +~ &x_{n+1}^2 + x_{n+2}^2 + \cdots + x_{n+9}^2 &= 10 \\
     ~ &x_{n+1}^2 + x_{n+2}^2 + \cdots + x_{n+9}^2 + x_{n+10}^2 &= 10
\end{align}
Subtracting them, we get that $x_n^2 = x_{n+10}^2$, so $(x_n^2)$ is periodic with period $10$.  So, if the sequence $(x_n)$ converges, then all of them must be equal to each other, and thus there are two sequences:  $(1, 1, 1, \dots)$ and $(-1, -1, -1, \dots)$.  The answer is $E$.

Comment: $x^2=y^2$ does not mean that $x=y$ must hold. The sequence is not necessarily periodic.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I meant $(x_n^2)$ is periodic with period $10$, not $(x_n)$ is periodic with period $10$.

Comment: But you are wrong that all of them must be equal to each other. The sequence $(-1,1,1,1,\dots)$ satisfies all of the conditions and so do infinitely many others.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $D$. Choose any subsequence $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ of $((-1)^n)_{n\ge1}$ such that $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $x_n=1$ for $n\ge N$.